# CSS Animation - How can I make this animation more fluently?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

First of all, I don't intend to use Javascript. Purely done in HTML & CSS.

I want to recreate [this animation](http://foxcodex.html.xdomain.jp/RepeatRotate.html) which is a gif made in AE, purely in CSS. This is right now what I have, but as you can see it slows down in the middle and makes a strange delay feel, anyone knows how I can get rid of that (It's probably something with bad placement/use of the `@keframes`)?

```css
.kader {
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin: 60px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: center;
}

.k1 {
    animation-name: animation_k1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.k2 {
    animation-name: animation_k2;
}

.k3 {
    animation-name: animation_k3;
}

.k4 {
    animation-name: animation_k4;
}

.k5 {
    animation-name: animation_k5;
}

@keyframes animation_k1 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    25% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="animatie">
            <div class="kader k1"></div>
            <div class="kader k2"></div>
            <div class="kader k3"></div>
            <div class="kader k4"></div>
            <div class="kader k5"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted to oblivion?

Comment: @JonasGiuro The exact reason is this: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".  I disagree with the attempt to close.  The minimal example is there.  It just needs to be moved from the fiddle to a stack snippet.

Comment: I edited the question to have the stack snippet.

Comment: try this answer: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/qxfdxh46/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things, all you need is `animation-direction: alternate;`

```css
.kader {
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin: 60px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    transform-origin: center;
}

.k1 {
    animation-name: animation_k1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.k2 {
    animation-name: animation_k2;
}

.k3 {
    animation-name: animation_k3;
}

.k4 {
    animation-name: animation_k4;
}

.k5 {
    animation-name: animation_k5;
}

@keyframes animation_k1 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="animatie">
            <div class="kader k1"></div>
            <div class="kader k2"></div>
            <div class="kader k3"></div>
            <div class="kader k4"></div>
            <div class="kader k5"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Depends, I took the static square as reference but yeah I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem corrrectly, it is your:

```
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

that is causing the problem. For an animation without the small "stop" in the middle. Try using linear in stead:

```
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

You could also try to create your own custom bezier curve to get the timing just right.

As pointed out it also seems that you´re overcomplicating your animation abit. Try using:

```
animation-direction: alternate;
```

Instead of animating both forwards and back.